# How to convert SQL many to many data model to firebase data model

Tags: sql, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

I am having troubles trying to convert my data model of an attendance system for a football trainer (I have done it as if it were a SQL normalized relational model) to a firebase model. Here is a picture of my relational model:

[image]

I was thinking about making 4 Collections also:

**Players**

**Attendance**

**Match**

**MatchType** (it can be friendly-match, tournament, practice, among others)

Comment: Check out this [youtube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ) about Firestore. Those videos should help you get a better grasp on how Firestore databases (NoSQL) work in contrast to a relational model. Videos #4 and #5 on that playlist should be especially helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this depends of how do you want to use the data. When I look at this it seems that one collection "Attandence" is enough, which in your schema is connecting all tables.

The idea of relational databases is that data should not be redundant, so every information is stored only once and connected by relation using keys like ex. PlayerID.

While in noSQL databases you does not care about data redundancy. So you are storing the same information (like player name) in many documents. The idea is to have everything in one document and do not create sophisticated queries to get information - just get document and you have everything.

So all depend how do you use information, which we do not know. You can put everything in one collection and just get all information from one document.

On the other hand you can create 4 collection with exactly the same fields as in SQL database and use in relational way just to have cheap, fast and serverless database engine.

What more you can change your solution any time as you do not define any schema.

So in Firestore you are free to choose any solution, you should think first how do you will use the information.

Comment: Thanks! Mainly i am going to display the attendances from all players to the different matches sorted by date. Displayed in something like a grid